# Firebase fails to deploy after migration to new Console

Tags: firebase

I just migrated my Firebase project to the new console (now it is firebase.google.com).

When I try to deploy my app via CLI, I keep getting the following error:
`Error: Invalid Firebase specified`

May I know how to deploy my app successfully after migration?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like an intermittent issue. I retried an hour later and no more errors.

Comment: I hope so. In all cases, this migration is not seamless